# Using SQLCMD to get multiple result sets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

#### How does one write, using SQLCMD:

- multiple result sets to one output file?
- or, multiple result sets to separate output files?

#### Discussion

After prototyping in SSMS, then moving to SQLCMD called from batch file, it's necessary to stay within the same connection (due to building some #temp tables along the way). The batch files will then be provided to production operations who will run them and give the output back to me for further processing.

```
CREATE TABLE #BatchFileType ( ... )
INSERT INTO #BatchFileType ( ... )
SELECT (...) FROM ...
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ...

CREATE TABLE #BrandingServiceDates ( ... )
INSERT INTO #BrandingServiceDates (
SELECT (...) FROM #BatchFileType JOIN (other tables)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ...

SELECT [result set 1]
SELECT [result set 2]
SELECT [result set n]
...
```

Then, based on #BrandingServiceDates, create multiple result sets which we want to write to output files. Each run is based on a date range. The goal here is to not have to redo the #temp table processing time for each result set.

This is a one-time run so looking to solve this with sqlcmd, batch files, and parameters.

```
sqlcmd -S %1 -i %2 -W -o %3 -k -s,
```

Where -o (from what I can tell) doesn't take an array of filenames.

Alternatives to SQLCMD are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before by using xp_cmdshell and sqlcmd to create delimited files. This example used a trusted connection back to the server that made the call. If there are any errors check the results written to @output. Or possibly the errors are written to the TXT file.

```
-- xp_cmdshell has a 8000 charater limit
declare @cmd varchar(8000)

-- create a global ##temp table

-- command string to output the table to a couple of different files
set @cmd = 'sqlcmd -E -S "[server]" -d "[database]" -Q"SET NOCOUNT ON select * from ##temp" -s"[delimiter]" -W -h-1 > "d:\file1.txt"'
         + ' & sqlcmd -E -S "[server]" -d "[database]" -Q"SET NOCOUNT ON select * from ##temp" -s"[delimiter]" -W -h-1 > "d:\file2.txt"'

-- replace dynamic values in the command string
set @cmd = replace(@cmd, '[server]', @server)
set @cmd = replace(@cmd, '[database]', @database)
set @cmd = replace(@cmd, '[delimiter]', @delimit)

-- execute the command and output results to a table variable
declare @output table (output varchar(max) null)
insert @output exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```